Find a diagonal matrix and the matrix eigenvalues
      mt = {{gb, 0, 0}, {0, gs, 0}, {0, 0, gm}};
      vt = {{1, vbs, vbm}, {vsb, 1, vsm}, {vmb, vms, 1}};
      T = mt . vt
      DiagonalizableMatrixQ[T]
      Eigenvalues[T]
      DiagonalMatrix[T] // MatrixForm

Hi, I need diagonalize matrix T and find the eigenvalues for this matrix. But, when I run this code I receive the answer like this:
{Root[-gb gm gs + gb gm gs vbm vmb + gb gm gs vbs vsb - 
     gb gm gs vbm vms vsb - gb gm gs vbs vmb vsm + 
     gb gm gs vms vsm + (gb gm + gb gs + gm gs - gb gm vbm vmb - 
     gb gs vbs vsb - gm gs vms vsm) #1 + (-gb - gm - 
      gs) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
 Root[-gb gm gs + gb gm gs vbm vmb + gb gm gs vbs vsb - 
     gb gm gs vbm vms vsb - gb gm gs vbs vmb vsm + 
     gb gm gs vms vsm + (gb gm + gb gs + gm gs - gb gm vbm vmb - 
    gb gs vbs vsb - gm gs vms vsm) #1 + (-gb - gm - 
    gs) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 Root[-gb gm gs + gb gm gs vbm vmb + gb gm gs vbs vsb - 
     gb gm gs vbm vms vsb - gb gm gs vbs vmb vsm + 
     gb gm gs vms vsm + (gb gm + gb gs + gm gs - gb gm vbm vmb - 
     gb gs vbs vsb - gm gs vms vsm) #1 + (-gb - gm - 
     gs) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}
 {Root[-gb gm gs + gb gm gs vbm vmb + gb gm gs vbs vsb - 
     gb gm gs vbm vms vsb - gb gm gs vbs vmb vsm + 
     gb gm gs vms vsm + (gb gm + gb gs + gm gs - gb gm vbm vmb - 
     gb gs vbs vsb - gm gs vms vsm) #1 + (-gb - gm - 
     gs) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
     Root[-gb gm gs + gb gm gs vbm vmb + gb gm gs vbs vsb - 
     gb gm gs vbm vms vsb - gb gm gs vbs vmb vsm + 
     gb gm gs vms vsm + (gb gm + gb gs + gm gs - gb gm vbm vmb - 
     gb gs vbs vsb - gm gs vms vsm) #1 + (-gb - gm - 
     gs) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 Root[-gb gm gs + gb gm gs vbm vmb + gb gm gs vbs vsb - 
     gb gm gs vbm vms vsb - gb gm gs vbs vmb vsm + 
     gb gm gs vms vsm + (gb gm + gb gs + gm gs - gb gm vbm vmb - 
     gb gs vbs vsb - gm gs vms vsm) #1 + (-gb - gm - 
     gs) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}

and I don't know what's wrong and what do I do now. Thanks for your help.

add // ToRadicals to remove the Roots  (just be careful not have MatrixFrom inside)

@Nasser Thank you so much. Is it possible diagonalize this matrix?

Try p = Transpose[Eigenvectors[T]]; Inverse[p] . T . p // FullSimplify // MatrixForm which generates diagonal matrix.  Notice that what you wrote DiagonalMatrix[T] is wrong. This does not do what you think it does. Need to use p'.T.p. See help for more information.

@Nasser Thanks for your help. I understand my mistake.

@march Hi, no I need find the diagonal matrix or the matrix eigenvalues. But I have an answer in this form I means with root that I can't change it. Thanks for your feedback.

But, you have diagonalized the matrix, in terms of the Root objects shown: Those root objects are the eigenvalues, and so DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[T]] is exactly the matrix $T$ represented in its eigenbasis. The linked question and answer explains how to use Root objects. So I'm not sure what your question is.

@march Yes, now I know that my question is about root. But before the friends answer I think my answer completely wrong.

But why do yo think it's wrong? If you want help, you're going to have to clarify what you actually think the problem is. "I don't know what's wrong and what do I do now" is not very helpful, because it seems to use that everything you've done is fine, but you haven't explained why you think something's wrong.
